# How to get the function handle within a decorator class which is used on a function?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-decorators

the following file structure is in a `testing` module within an overall `project` folder:

```
project/
│── testing/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── store.py
│   └── store_functions.py
│
└── main.py
```

**testing/store.py**

```
class Store:
    
    registered = []
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Store.registered.append(self)
    
    def __call__(self, func):
        pass
```

**testing/store_functions.py**

```
@Store('test-xyz')
def my_test_function(testname):
    pass
```

Basic idea is, I would like to import the `testing` module somewhere and the defined functions with a `@Store` decorator should be automatically be collected and stored within the `Store.registered`.
So that inside **main.py**:

```
import testing # this automatically collects all @Store decorators and puts all of them into Store.registered

registered_stores = Store.registered
```

But my problem is within the `Store.__init__` function I somehow can't get the function handle of `my_test_function`:
**testing/store.py**

```
class Store:
    
    registered = []
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # here I need access to the actual function this decorator was assigned to for examle:
        # @Store('test-xyz')
        # def my_test_function(testname):
        #     pass

        # I would need access to the function handle of my_test_function
```

Is this somehow possible?
Or in which way I would need to change my code to get this design/approach working?
Any help and/or hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Does the text inside `@Store('test-xyz')` do something? is it necesary?

Comment: Yes, it is also processed inside the Store.__init__ and stored as a self. member. I thought leaving this out would make the problem description cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [Roy Cohen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65824651/1208424), if you'd like to keep all of the decorator logic within the `Store` class, you'll have to construct it a bit differently.

### Preface: Understanding Decorators that Accept Arguments

First, remember how decorators work:

```py
@foo
def bar():
    pass

# is equivalent to:

def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

It's important to understand that the expression after the `@` is expected to evaluate to a *callable* that takes a single argument, which is the callable that it is decorating; in this case, `bar`. With that in mind, when we want to create a decorator that can take arguments, we end up with a subtle, but very important change in behavior when we write something like:

```py
@foo('wowza')
def frobnicate():
    pass

# is equivalent to:

def frobnicate():
    pass
frobnicate = foo('wowza')(frobnicate)
```

Again, the expression after the `@` should evaluate to a callable. However, now our expression is a function **call** rather than a function **object**! As a consequence, the *result* of calling `foo('wowza')` is used as the decorator, which means that result will then be attempted to be used as a callable and passed `frobnicate` as an argument. If the result *is* a callable, then great! But it probably isn't, so such a decorator must be constructed differently.

### Creating the Storage Decorator

Here's the implementation; going off the examples in your question, you want to be able to construct `Storage` instances with an argument that is then stored in the instance.

```py
import functools

class Storage:
    registered = []

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        # Note that we don't have the decorated function object yet. This is
        # intentional! Remember how decorators are evaluated! All we do here is
        # store our decorator arguments.
        self.value = value

        # create any other needed attributes

    # This is our "callable" that takes in the decorated function!
    def __call__(self, func):
        # Using type avoids hard-coding the class name
        type(self).registered.append(func)

        # do something with self.value if needed
        # do something with func if needed

        # The usual functools.wraps call. This preserves the decorated
        # function's name and docstring.
        @functools.wraps(func)

        # This should be familiar; it's just like writing a normal decorator.
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # do something with func, func(), and/or self.value if needed
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        # This function object is what the name of the decorated function is
        # bound to.
        return wrapper
```

Here's a version without all the comments:

```py
import functools

class Storage:
    registered = []

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self, func):
        type(self).registered.append(func)
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Applying the decorator works as expected:

```py
@Storage('test-xyz')
def my_test_function(testname):
    pass
```

Be aware that if you want the decorator argument to be optional, you still need to "call" the decorator even if you're not passing any arguments; just like you would when instantiating any other class:

```py
@Storage()
def my_test_function2(testname):
    pass
```

---

If you'd like a more in-depth explanation on creating different kinds of decorators (including ones like this) with plenty of examples, I highly recommend RealPython's [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators). It's quite thorough and goes into deeper detail than I have here.

Comment: the `wrapper` function is equivalent to `func`, so you can just return `func`.

Comment: @RoyCohen If you take my comment-stripped example verbatim, yes, but the OP didn't include details about what else the decorator would be doing; hence why I mentioned using `self.value`, `func`, and/or `func()` in the body of `wrapper` in the commented version. It's just a skeleton.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I would define a function to take in arguments such as `'text-xyz'` and return a decorator who will call `Store`:

```py
def store(*args, **kwargs):
    def decor(func):
        Store(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return decor

class Store:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        # use func, args aand kwargs
```

Usage:

```py
@store('test-xyz')  # note the lower-case store
def my_test_function(testname):
    pass
```